# SQR installation in solaris

Tags: installation, solaris, sqr

we were migrating our application from hp-ux system to solaris. now we are in the need to install SQR in solaris. Is there a way to install SQR in Solaris 10.

Answer (score 0):

According to [**Oracle Lifetime Support Policy - Oracle Fusion Middleware**](http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lifetime-support-middleware-069163.pdf), Hyperion SQR extended support ended in 2018.

If you have an Oracle support contract, I'd open a support case there.  If you don't have a support contract with Oracle and you want a version of SQR that will run on Solaris 10, you probably need to get an Oracle support contract.